# how to use ajax timer in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer

dear all..
i'm new to ajax timer, since someone tell me to use it for make my page can auto refresh.
can you tell how to use it for my jquery page?

Comment: You want your page to refresh after a certain time? And you also want to display this time to the users?

Comment: i want my page can auto refresh every 4 seconds without press refresh button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get you but you can refresh a page every 4 seconds with javascript like this,

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = window.location.href;
},4000)​;
```

or via html using `meta` tags like this,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4">
```

Comment: how about reading [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479551/Reloading-The-Page.htm)